# How to replace href/src value in JSX from relative path to full path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

project:

```
├── img
│   └── header.jpg
├── index.html
├── js
│   └── react.js
└── jsx
    └── header.jsx
```

header.jsx

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <img className="header" src="./img/header.jpg" alt="header"/>
        );
    }
});
```

When i deploy static files(js,css,image) to CDN host,the header.png full path will be **http:// cdn.com/img/header.jpg**;

But my project host is  **http:// example.com**, the header.jpg can't be load, so **i want to find a way to replace the src value(example:./img/header.jpg -->http:// cdn.com/img/header.jpg )**

-----By the way------

Hope using gulp to solve this problem;
I fond gulp-assetpaths is good way to replace in HTML, but not work in jsx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at Webpack which handles this really well. What you do is something like this:

```
var path = require('./img/header.jpg');
return <img className="header" src={path} alt="header" />
```

When you require the image, you get back the url to wherever that image is placed after the build has completed. There are Webpack loaders that already handles this (like file-loader), but you can always create your own loader which rewrites the path to your CDN. Note that Webpack treats a `require` in Javascript the same was as it treats `url` in CSS, so it doesn't matter where you reference the image, it'll still be passed through your loader.

You can of course use different strategies for production and development, so you'd only return the CDN url for a production build.

Comment: Webpack is a way to solve this; But it will make code more complex;

Comment: Thanks!   I think develop a tool can automatically replace the path is a better way.    :D

Comment: My experience is that Webpack gets much less complex than grunt/gulp. Since Webpack knows about all your frontend assets, Webpack can be smarter about these things. I've converted several 1000 line Gulpfiles to around 50 lines of Webpack config.

Comment: 1000 line Guilfile to 50 line Webpack config, that's really cool; I will try to use Webpack next time

Comment: @AndersEkdahl: Is there a way to define a global variable and use it to form the path for all the assets. What I mean is, i define a variable called `context` globally and then append the value of text everywhere like `src=.{conext}/img/header.jpg`?